# Remove multiple slashes at the end of a string and leave one only in R

Tags: r

For my case, it's an web strings, but here I will just give an easier example:`

```
df = data.frame(Strings = c("abc/d/e/f////", "abc///", "/", "a/bc/d/////"))
```

The result that I want to gain is make the string which is ended with multiple "/" into there is only one "/" left at the end of the strings.

Which means that for the df I gave above, I want to get a result like this:

```
df_result = data.frame(Strings = c("abc/d/e/f/", "abc/", "/", "a/bc/d/"))
```

Thanks for answering my question.

Comment: Could you remove the pictures of code and simply copy and paste into the question?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! To help you effectively, we need all the necessary information to reproduce your problem, i.e. *working* code and example data. There are several [*ways to provide data*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610), probably adding the output of `dput(head(<yourData>))` to your question is sufficient. Avoid providing code as an image! Consider [*How to make a great reproducible example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly, cheers!

Comment: oh Sorry for my question, this is my first time to ask questions here. I apologize for my ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use:

```
string1<-"abc/d/e/f///"
gsub("/(?=/{1,})","",string1,perl=TRUE)
#[1] "abc/d/e/f/"
```

Comment: i also found out that
gsub("\\/{2,}$", "/", df$Strings) works too.

Comment: Well, it depends. I used 1 to match anything greater than or equal to 1. 2 would match anything greater than or equal to 2.